# CrudRepository#save not persisting data in mySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to save an entity (`Event`) to a mySql database running locally. When I try to do so using `CrudRepository`, data is not persisted to the database. Why does this happen and how can I resolve this issue?

I don't see what I'm doing wrong, as the `CrudRepository#findAll` works as expected.

Here's some context:

**Properties**

```
# Spring
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# Application
monitor.db.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
monitor.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/system_monitor_dev?useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
monitor.db.username=SYSTEM_MONITOR
monitor.db.password=<omitted>
```

**DataSourceConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(DataSourceConfig.REPOSITORIES_PACKAGE)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataSourceConfig {

    private static final String MODEL_PACKAGE = "be.thibaulthelsmoortel.monitor.model";
    static final String REPOSITORIES_PACKAGE = "be.thibaulthelsmoortel.monitor.repositories";

    private final DatabaseProperties databaseProperties;

    @Autowired
    public DataSourceConfig(DatabaseProperties databaseProperties) {
        this.databaseProperties = databaseProperties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.scanPackages(MODEL_PACKAGE);
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource dataSource) {
        final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return initializer;
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(getJpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(MODEL_PACKAGE);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .username(databaseProperties.getUsername())
            .password(databaseProperties.getPassword())
            .url(databaseProperties.getUrl())
            .driverClassName(databaseProperties.getDriverClassName())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter getJpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }
}
```

**Event**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "date_time")
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**EventRepository**

```
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {

}
```

**EventService**

```
public interface EventService {

    Event findById(long id) throws ObjectNotFoundException;

    Event save(Event event);

    Iterable<Event> findAll();
}
```

**EventServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class EventServiceImpl implements EventService {

    private EventRepository eventRepository;

    @Autowired
    public EventServiceImpl(EventRepository eventRepository) {
        this.eventRepository = eventRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Event findById(long id) throws ObjectNotFoundException {
        Optional<Event> optionalEvent = eventRepository.findById(id);
        if (optionalEvent.isPresent()) {
            return optionalEvent.get();
        }

        throw new ObjectNotFoundException(Event.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public Event save(Event event) {
        return eventRepository.save(event);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Event> findAll() {
        return eventRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>be.thibaulthelsmoortel</groupId>
<artifactId>system-monitor</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>System Monitor</name>
<description>Application for monitoring any kind of system events.</description>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>

    <log4j.version>2.11.1</log4j.version>
    <mysql-connector-java.version>8.0.12</mysql-connector-java.version>
    <spring.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.0.6.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>

    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <mockito.version>2.23.0</mockito.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Logging -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other -->

    <!-- javassist required for datasource config -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Testing -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

**Attempt**
The actual save attempt attached underneath does not persist any data to the database and also does not print any sql statement to the console (sql statement is printed and executed when using `CrudRepository#findAll`.

```
Event newEvent = new Event();
            //newEvent.setId(2);
            newEvent.setName("New event");
            newEvent.setDescription("A new event arose from the ashes.");
            newEvent.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
            Event savedEvent = eventService.save(newEvent);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Try using @Transactional annotation on your service class.

Comment: Where `DatabaseProperties` come from?

Comment: Are you sure that your code invoked?

Comment: why don't you try JpaRepository instead of crudRepository?

Comment: @PoojaAggarwal no error whatsoever. I tried using `@Transactional`, but that did not help.

Comment: @talex `DataProperties` is just a class that contains all properties entries prefixed by `monitor.db`.

Comment: @GauravRai1512 I have tried replacing `CrudRepository` by `JpaRepository` in my `EventRepository`, but that does not help either.

Comment: Can you post the pom file?

Comment: @EugenCovaci I have updated the question with the pom.xml contents.

Comment: This is not a proper way to use Spring Boot. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html